# Backup LMDB database from Hyperledger Sawtooth

Tags: lmdb, consensus, hyperledger-sawtooth, sparse-file

I have a sawtooth 1.1 dockerized network, and i'm trying to backup the database from the validators so i can put down every container and then recover in case of  a disaster.

Trying to achieve this i proceed as followed:

1. Stopped the all containers;
2. Backed up all the files of one of the validators on **/var/lib/sawtooh/** using

   **cp --sparse=always [file] [file_backup]**
3. Removed all the containers using **docker-compose down**
4. Started a fresh network with **docker-compose up**
5. Stopped all containers using **docker-compose stop**
6. Copied the files backed up on **step 2** to the new validators using the command of that same step
7. Restarted all network using **docker-compose restart**

After this i could repare that the states were correct, users on the blockchain have the same balance as before of the docker-compose down. But the blockchain **doesn't process new transactions**.
The only error that i've found in the logs, was in the **sawtooth-poet-engine**
i believe during the consensus as it show on the this image,
[ERROR_IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo7Mb.png).

So my question is, does anybody tried to do this with success or have any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the same thing and it worked for me.
One possible problem is file permissions and ownership.
Use the `cp -p` option to preserve ownership and permissions:

`cp -p --sparse=always [file] [file_backup]`

Also verify the ownership and permissions are correct with `ls -l /var/lib/sawtooth` .
They should be all read/write by owner and owned by user/group sawtooth.  If not, fix the ownership with something like

`chown sawtooth:sawtooth /var/lib/sawtooth /var/lib/sawtooth/*
chmod u+rw /var/lib/sawtooth /var/lib/sawtooth/*
chmod ugo+r /var/lib/sawtooth/block-* /var/lib/sawtooth/txn_receipts-00.lmdb*`

Comment: Tried what you said and now i don't have the error, but can't do transactions and i don't see any error on any log, and noticed that the permissions are read and write to root, even before. Tried the backup with cp -p and then fix the owner like you said, but i still have the same problem. There is a piece of information that i didn't said that maybe as something to do with this. To be able to use cp --sparse=always i've created 3 volumes (one for each validator) that points to the /var/lib/sawtooth and then i execute my backup and restore commands pointing to the volume dir on the host.

Comment: i've noticed on the poet-engine logs that they are stuck, i can try do transactions but even with the logs on debug nothing new happens there. In this link is the log, i've marked the moment i changed the LMDB files, pls take a look
https://justpaste.it/5360d

Comment: You are supposed to stop everything when you copy the files.

Comment: Yes, and i do everything with containers stopped and then i start the containers.

Comment: My compose is similar to this 
https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/1.1/app_developers_guide/sawtooth-default-poet.yaml

Should i save the files on poet-share and then do a restore of them too?

Comment: I am not sure the problem is copying the files.

Look at the file and directory permissions of the old and copied files and see if they are the same. Use the `cmp --verbose` command and compare the old and copied files--they should be the same.

Comment: It could be that restarting the containers are the problem. Can you stop and restart the containers OK without copying the files?

Comment: As far as what's in the containers, the contents will stay there if you don't reboot the guest host where the containers run.  Otherwise you need to save /etc/sawtooth/, /var/lib/sawtooth/, /var/log/sawtooth/ and the ~/.sawtooth directory where you have the user keys (often /root/.sawtooth).